# Linq Group By in nested array

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a List of Incident object (List) with the following way:

```
  Incident
    -Title
    -Category
      -Name
      -Subcategory
        -Name
```

Im looking a Linq eficient way, to get the count of incidents related to each category and subcategories

- expected obj result -

```
CategoryName        
Count        
Subcategories           
   SubcategoryName          
   Count
```

```
 var categoryGroup = incidentsModel.GroupBy(i => i.Category.Name);

        var categoryGroupAndSubcategoryGroup =  categoryGroup.Select(group =>
        {
            var subcategories = group.SelectMany(item => item.Category.Subcategories).GroupBy(item => item.Name).Select(item =>  new IncidentSubcategoriesCount
            {
                SubcategoryName = item.Key,
                SubcategoryCount = item.Count()
            });

             return new IncidentCategoriesCount
             {
                 CategoryName = group.Key,
                 catagoryCount = group.Count(),
                 Subcategories = subcategories
             };
        });


        return categoryGroupAndSubcategoryGroup;
```

testing  @hannan answer  the code above return:

```
[
{
    "categoryName": "Alumbrado",
    "catagoryCount": 1,
    "subcategories": [
        {
            "subcategoryName": "Lamparas",
            "subcategoryCount": 1
        }
    ]
},
{
    "categoryName": "Seguridad",
    "catagoryCount": 3,
    "subcategories": [
        {
            "subcategoryName": "Narcotráfico",
            "subcategoryCount": 3
        },
        {
            "subcategoryName": "Robo",
            "subcategoryCount": 3
        }
    ]
}
```

]

CategoryName and CategoryCount are OK, the error is in SubcategoriesCount, "Narcotrafico" SubcategoryCount must be 2 and "Robo" SubcategoryCount must be 1 so the Total is 3.

Expected result

```
   [
{
    "categoryName": "Alumbrado",
    "catagoryCount": 1,
    "subcategories": [
        {
            "subcategoryName": "Lamparas",
            "subcategoryCount": 1
        }
    ]
},
{
    "categoryName": "Seguridad",
    "catagoryCount": 3,
    "subcategories": [
        {
            "subcategoryName": "Narcotráfico",
            "subcategoryCount": 2
        },
        {
            "subcategoryName": "Robo",
            "subcategoryCount": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

]

Answer (score 0):

Use Select Many then you can group any way you want

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Incident> indcidents = new List<Incident>();

            var results = indcidents.SelectMany(x => x.catogories
                .SelectMany(y => y.subcategories.Select(z =>
                    new { title = x.Title, CategoryName = y.Name, Subcategory = z.Name }
            ))).ToList();
        }
    }
    public class Incident
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public List<Category> catogories { get; set; }
    }
    public class Category
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Subcategory> subcategories { get; set; }
    }
    public class Subcategory
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if u are looking for all categories and subcategories I'm afraid u have to do nested groupBy

```
public class Subcategory
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Subcategory> Categories { get; set; } = new List<Subcategory>()
}

public class Incident { 
    public List<Category> Categories { get; set; } = new List<Category>()
}


var categoryGroup = new Incident().Categories.GroupBy(category => category.Name);

var categoryGroupAndSubcategoryGroup = categoryGroup.Select(group =>
{
    var subcategories = group.SelectMany(item => item.Categories).GroupBy(item => item.Name).Select(item => new
    {
        Name = item.Key,
        count = item.Count()
    })


    return
    new
    {
        Name = group.Key,
        Count = group.Count()

        Subcategories = subcategories
    }
})
```